# Getting Component name by mouse listeners

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, joptionpane

I am working on jpanel with some textareas in it

I have given mouse listener to it

update: problem  is when I moved a component with mouse, popup window shows "null component is moved." What I want is,

**when a component in a panel moved by mouse then the pop up window should show which component is moved**

edited:

I used

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me)

{

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you released :"+ me.getComponent().getName());

}

to get name of the textarea. is it right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your code where you (try to) determine which component is moved

Comment: quite easilly and possible, but maybe (avoid guessing) no idea what do you talking about, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame, JPanel and two JTextAreas

Comment: please help me anybody i am new to java

Comment: Have you set the name for the component in question, using [Component.setName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName(java.lang.String)) method ? If not, then it has to be `null` by default :-)